# Asynchronous code in swift

Tags: swift, xcode, asynchronous

I am new to swift...I cannot figure out how to get back to the main thread after an asynchronous call. I am accessing a database via URLSession, and i have tried completion handlers and delegates. but none of them go back to the main thread. so if i want to update a label with information from the database i have to use DispatchQueue.main. So what happens if i have to go back to the database again? Will I end up in a third thread?

My app starts with a login screen, I verify your credentials (URLSession) and then would like to start the next view. Is everything now in the background thread??

Comment: Share your code with us please

Answer (score 0):

Let' say you have this: (follow the comments)

```
private func backgroundLogIn(username:String, password: String, callback:@escaping(Bool,String) -> Void) {
    // this function gets the user's detail and returns a callback from the background queue.
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {  //<-- we are in a background queue, however I will use qos with better priority since the user is waiting for response. 
        // post to login api via URLSession
        // doing ... work .... :) 
        // ahhh.. we get a response from our api & decode it 
        callback(true, "authorized") //<--- set our callback 
    }
}


func login() { 
     // when this function gets called, it goes in the background queue to talk with your login api, and then come back to main queue and act based on the result.
    // since we are using callback (aka closure), be careful for reference cycle
    backgroundLogIn(username: "lamar", password: "1238212") { (isAuthorized, msg) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in  //<-- we are now in the main queue since its only job is to interact with objects/views in your controller 
            if isAuthorized {
                // present or push your intended viewController
                // self? instead of self to avoid reference cycle 
            } else {
                // show error using alertController or whatever.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like a dispatch-group to make asynchronous calls.
1. define it as  let myGroup = DispatchGroup()
2. then call the function ->

```
 'self.createQuestions {() -> () in
                myGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
                    self.newQuestion()}}'
```

3. the createQuestion function looks like this

   'func createQuestions(handleComplete:(()->())){
   //code to excite and wait for finish
   handleComplete()`

}

hope this works :)